# Apple Distribution Provisioning Profile becomes invalid 30 min after creation

Tags: ios, xcode, profile, provisioning-profile

I noticed one of our AppStore Distritbution profiles is Invalid and currently a blocker for app submission for us.

I have edited it, re-generated it. It shows as **valid for 30 minutes** or so, and then becomes invalid again. Any suggestions? I was not able to find anything on Google or here.

I found a related thread (which is closed) where they say, that app was uploaded with an invalid profile and it went into review (no follow up after that).

There was also a suggestion to delete the profile alltogether and create a new one, but wouldn't that cause an issue with current app installations which is on the app store now?

[Link to related (closed) topic](https://devforums.apple.com/message/967222#967222)

Comment: It will not create any problem if you delete the PP and regenerate it. Just make sure you are creating the new PP for same bundle identifier..

Comment: Any solution? I've started running into the almost identical problem. It's a Wildcard Distribution Profile and it just goes invalid on the Member Center for no known reason. Oddly, it still works in Xcode, but it won't download and will vanish on refresh. I've tried creating a brand new profile, but it does the same thing. I do have some 3rd party vendor developers as members on the account, but I can't think of anything they could do which would invalidate the profile.

Comment: We have ignored this issue and submitted the app anyway in this case - it went well. As this issue didn't cause any other concerns to us we did ignore it after that - not sure if issue persisted for a long time after that (I have no access to account I had this issue on anymore). Please drop a comment here if you will find any solution for people who will have a similar issue in the future.